# asp.net mvc custom authorize roles attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to have the following roles applied to most of my controllers like

```
this[Authorize(Roles="SysAdmin,Admin,Support")].
```

How can I refactor this code in base controller without specifying roles for every controller?
Thanks

Comment: Decorate `[Authorize(Roles="SysAdmin,Admin,Support")]` to the base controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is defined as

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, 
    AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
```

As you see, it is defined with `Inherited = true`, so simply applying attribute to base controller should help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you be more specific? I am very new to MVC.

Comment: As you said, you can just apply attribute to base controller and Authorization will work for every derived controller. This is from c#, not asp.net mvc :)

Answer (score 0):

take a look to FluentFilters lib http://fluentfilters.codeplex.com/ It provides a way to apply global filters simply.